# number of spark partitions when reading from buckets - S3 - GCS

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, partitioning

S3 and GCS are not block storage as opposite as HDFS so the way how Spark creates partitions when reading from these sources is not that clear to me.
I am now reading from GCS but I get 2 partitions for small files (10 bytes), and also for medium files 100 MBs.

Has anyone an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally it's a configuration option, "how big to lie about partition size".

Comment: Do you mean configuration in Spark side?
like split.size or something like that?

Comment: yes; it's either that or a default value of the store/format